# Smart-Table - AngularJs - Wrap within a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, smart-table

I'm very new to AngularJs and trying to "wrap" the Smart-Table plugin inside a directive.
I can get the rows but the pagination is not showing

Currently this is what I did.

```
    app.directive('grid', [ function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: function (element, attrs) {
            return '<table class="table table-striped">'
                          + '<thead>'
                          + '    <tr>'
                                  + '<th st-ratio="20" st-sort="Team">Team</th>'
                                  + '<th st-ratio="20" st-sort="TeamFreq">Team Freq</th>'
                                  + '<th st-ratio="10" st-sort="TeamSac">Team Sac</th>'
                                  + '<th st-ratio="30" st-sort="Priority">Priority</th>'
                              + '</tr>'
                          + '</thead>'
                          + '<tbody>'
                              + '<tr ng-repeat="row in dataset">'
                                 + ' <td>{{row.firstName}}</td>'
                                  + '<td>{{row.lastName | uppercase}}</td>'
                                  + '<td>{{row.age}}</td>'
                                  + '<td>{{row.email}}</td>'
                              + '</tr>'
                          + '</tbody>'
                          + '<tfoot>'
                              + '<tr>'
                                 + '<td colspan="4" class="text-center">'
                                  + '<div class="pagination pagination-xs m-top-none pull-right"  st-pagination="1" st-items-by-page="itemsByPage" st-displayed-pages="4"></div>'
                                  + '</td>'
                              + '</tr>'
                          + '</tfoot>'
                      + '</table>';

        },
        scope: {

        },
        controller: function ($scope) {

        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            var nameList = ['Pierre', 'Pol', 'Jacques', 'Robert', 'Elisa'], familyName = ['Dupont', 'Germain', 'Delcourt', 'bjip', 'Menez'];
            function createRandomItem() {
                var
                    firstName = nameList[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)],
                    lastName = familyName[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)],
                    age = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
                    email = firstName + lastName + '@@whatever.com',
                    balance = Math.random() * 3000;

                return {
                    firstName: firstName,
                    lastName: lastName,
                    age: age,
                    email: email,
                    balance: balance
                };
            }

            scope.rowCollection = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                scope.rowCollection.push(createRandomItem());
            }
            scope.dataset = [].concat(scope.rowCollection);
        }
    };
}]);
```

My html contains this tag

```
  <grid st-table="dataset"></grid>
```

This code is just a test, the data will be passed using a service.. and the template will be dynamic.
I need some help :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the pagination to show when I was using smart-table in a directive the other day. Turns out it had nothing to do with the directive and I just pulled/updated to the very latest version of smart-table from GitHub and it all worked. I started looking at the what had changed but got side tracked and moved onto something more productive, happy that it was now working.
Version I have that appears to be working fine is tagged 1.4.2.

With dynamic data from a service, however, I think you're going to need to look at the st-safe-src attribute too. Although I'm new to this whole Angular / smart-table business too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to match the st-table value and the st-pagination value to get the pagination to show.